# What is the name of this combined button/popupbutton?

Tags: buttons, design-patterns, menu, terminology, dropdown

This button is in the new Firefox, but what is the name of it?

[image: Firefox combi-button]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This type of button is usually called a 'Split Button'.

The glossary of the *Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines* defines the term 'split button' as:

> A bipartite command button that
>   includes a small button with a
>   downward pointing triangle on the
>   rightmost portion of the main button.
>   Users click the triangle to display
>   variations of a command in a drop-down
>   menu. See also: command button.
>   [ http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c ]

MSDN's *Ribbon Framework Control Library* defines a 'Split Button' as:

> The Split Button is a composite
>   control with which the user can select
>   a default value bound to a primary
>   button, or select from a list of
>   mutually exclusive values displayed in
>   a drop-down list bound to a secondary
>   button.
>   [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940505(VS.85).aspx ]

Answer (score 10):

Jquery UI calls it a 'Split Button' - http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton

Not a bad name, I would say.

Answer (score 4):

They've also been called Muttons - https://web.archive.org/web/20121116015828/http://hanamidesign.com/blog/ux-pattern-mutton-menu-button/

Comment: Link is broken. I tried https://web.archive.org/web/20150421053832/http://hanamidesign.com/blog/ux-pattern-mutton-menu-button/ , but that gave me an error of "The web service to this account has been limited temporarily!"

Comment: @MikeEng try an earlier snapshot https://web.archive.org/web/20121116015828/http://hanamidesign.com/blog/ux-pattern-mutton-menu-button/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know the formal term for this type of button but in my team we tend to refer to it as a 'multi(call-to)-action button' ... I am certain there is a better name than that however!! It is used extensively in the Apple store also, so as a consequence I suspect will be seeing them ever increasingly in the future! ;)